# How to add second text view just after completion of the first textview

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add second textview, just after completion of the first one. Linear layout with orientation horizontal didn't help. 
Any other alternatives? Please suggest!

Comment: Hello and welcome! Can you share some code from what you have and what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, we use HTML text for this information. 
We can use as many text styles as we want for different texts. With this way, you can set properties for each texts differently.

For Example: `<HTML><text1><text2></HTML>`

In the above, you can define text properties independently. Finally place this text in Textview. So we can achieve this using single TextView itself.

Example:

```
String str = "<a>This is a  <font color='#800000FF'> blue text</font> and this is a <font color='red'> red text</font> </a>";

TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(str, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT));
```